# in map i got a error in GoogleMap tag .after i clean, its get error free,offen for every modification i am clean

Tags: android

GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();

error:
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#getFragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: You are using functionality that requires API level 11, while the current minimum is set to API level 8. In your `androidmanifest.xml` file, change the `minSDKVersion` to at least 11.

Otherwise, if you do want to support lower API levels, you need to use the support fragment manager in the compatibility package. Enough documentation about that online.

Comment: Also, why cleaning helps is because it's a lint error and by default lint is only run on modified files on save. Clean removes lint markers and does not modify the file. Modifying the file or running lint manually will reintroduce the lint error.